# What plugin to use for internationalization with jQuery Mobile and RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, internationalization, requirejs

I'm using `requireJS` along with `Jquery Mobile` and have started to look at options of internationalizing an application.

Right now available languages (EN/DE/FR) are serverd from the database. When the user picks a new language I'm doing a changepage on the current page setting `jqm option` `allowSamePageTransition=true`, which re-fetches the page and adds it to the DOM (it's in the DOM twice, but that's ok for now.

Since the app eventually should work offline, I want to remove the languages from the database and store/server via JSON/Javascript, so switching languages would trigger the same event, only this time the translations will be served as JSON and I'm building stuff on the client.

I have been trying do this with the `i18n` plugin provided by `requireJS` and while this was super easy to setup, when the user switches languages manually I'm stuck with having to re-load the full application to display the new language, which is a no-go.

**Question**:
I have read a few questions on internationalization and suggested frameworks, but am unsure which way to go and haven't really found any alternative.

Considering these:
  - should be small and fast
  - needs to work with JQM
  - should use JSON/.po files I can build server side for download and keeping in cache/localstorage
  - plural rules etc are ok, but not a must

what do you recommend using? What have been your experiences?

Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might hava a look at http://i18next.com:

- rather major
- comes with requirejs support
- you could use JSON -> but has a converter for .mo/.po files
- proper pluralization
- more features (context, stringf, interpolation, localstorage caching, ...)
- has even a UI to translate your stuff
- should run with jqm

We personally use it a lot in combination with backbone.js and handlebars template engine. But will work with different setups as well.

I started the work on i18next because i wasn't happy with the current situation. Most libraries where to complicated or had just not enough to offer proper localization - so i started i18next - which now is rather popular.

Comment: Good. Thanks for the tip. I will give it a try fiddling into my requireJS setup. I'm using Jquery Mobile navigation (vs backbone) and have my own "templating" tool, so should be no problem. I will post when it's working.

Comment: if you encounter any problems feel free to open an issue on github.

Comment: Did you have success integrating i18next with JQM? I am also investigating this and would like to know your success mileage...

Comment: I myself didn't done this - as i don't use JQM. But i heard from others doing so - not sure where the biggest problem are - as it seems to be plain old html.

Comment: @jamuhl: looks nice. I'm starting to play around with i18next. Can you tell out of the box, if you can translate link title attributes?

Comment: can't use it with cordova